# Tensorflow/Keras: tf.reshape to Concatenate after multiple Conv2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am implementing multiple Conv2D layers, then I concatenate the outputs.

```
x = Conv2D(f, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1))(input)
y = Conv2D(f, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(2,2))(input)
output = Concatenate()([x, y])
```

As you know, different kernel size produces different output shape. Although I can do this:

```
x = Conv2D(f, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same")(input)
y = Conv2D(f, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(input)
output = Concatenate()([x, y])
```

But that would increase the number of channels a lot, which makes me run out of memory.  I can also calculate the output shape, but that would be inconvenient if I change the kernel size.
I tried:

```
y = tf.reshape(y, x.shape)
```

But I gave the error:
`ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor`
Is there an easy way to concatenate the outputs from multiple Conv2D layers?

Comment: If you want to concatenate your channels will increase. If you are trying to reshape the output of layers add complete error traceback along with the code you tried.

Comment: @AniketBote yeah the channels will increase, but the image size after big Conv2D kernels I think it can reduce computation cost.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your comment. If your input image has 3 channels the output of `Concatenate` will have 6 channels ie`(28,28,3) -> (28,28,6)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes that's what I need, but the problem is since I want to pass `inputs` through multiple `Conv2D` layers in parallel, so the output's shape of each layer is not equal so I cannot concatenate, but I also don't want to use "same" padding. I tried tf.reshape but it gave me the error above, so now I am stuck.

Comment: You have to use zero paddings in order to increase the dimensions. Reshaping doesn't increase the dimensions. It just changes the shape. If you want I can post an answer which adds zero paddings.

Comment: That I can do, still I have to calculate the output shape of every layer to add the Zero Padding, which may requires a lot of work. Is there any shortcut?

Comment: I don't think there are any shortcuts for that in TensorFlow.You can plot a graph of your model and make the layer whose output shape you want as output layers. I'll post an answer as a reference for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot concatenate outputs of two layers if their shapes don't match. You can utilize the `ZeroPadding2D` layer to add rows and columns with `0` values in order to match the shapes of outputs.

Here is the shortest example along with the shapes.

**Code:**

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import *
import tensorflow as tf

input = Input(shape = (28,28,3))
x = Conv2D(3, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1))(input)
y = Conv2D(3, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(2,2))(input)
z = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(7,7))(y)
output = Concatenate()([x, z])
model = Model(inputs = input, outputs = output)

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, 'my_first_model.png', show_shapes=True)
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

For this example, I have taken input shape as `(28,28,3)`. You can add your own input shape and accordingly change the number of padding rows and columns to be added.

You can take a look at the documentation of `ZeroPadding2D` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ZeroPadding2D)

Comment: Thanks for the idea.